# How to select a fixed number of characters after a word with javascript (google script)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-docs, re2

I want to the Google doc script do something like this.

*When you have found the string `Dernière modification` in the document, add the 24 characters next to it inside the `var chercher`.* (line 4 in my code)

I only know there are always 24 characters after those words, not what inside.

Like this : `Dernière modification | 2019 02 08 | 13:24:46`

The date and hour number are changing each times

---

Actually i'm not a developper, I only have little bit of knowledge in javascript
That's why i'm here

I have read this, but I don't know where to start without skills

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/RegExp

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String)

---

```
function insertAtCursor() {
    var id = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId();
    var update = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getLastUpdated();
    var chercher = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText('Dernière modification');
    var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(update, "GMT+01:00", "yyyy MM dd '|' HH:mm:ss");
    var modification = 'Dernière modification | ' + formattedDate;
    //var element = curseur.insertText(modification);

    if (chercher === modification) {
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor().insertText('reussite');
    } else {
        DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getCursor().insertText('raté');
    }
}
```

---

Actually the result are `var chercher = Dernière modification`

And I want `var chercher = Dernière modification | 2019 02 08 | 13:24:46` with different number each time.

I expect something like this ~ : `var chercher = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody().findText('Dernière modification'`**++\w 24**`);`

I'm open to any idea

Answer (score 1):

- The regex for any character is `.`
- You can quantify regex groups by `{}`
- `findText()` will only return a `rangeElement`. You should get the element and offseted text to get the matched string.

#### Code Snippet:

```
function search() {
  var rangeElement = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument()
    .getBody()
    .findText('Dernière modification.{24}');

  var chercher = rangeElement
    .getElement()
    .asText()
    .getText()
    .substring(
      rangeElement.getStartOffset(),
      rangeElement.getEndOffsetInclusive()+1
    );
  Logger.log(chercher);
}
```

#### References:

- [re2Syntax](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax)
- [FindText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#findText(String))
- [RangeElement](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range-element)
- [String#Substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)